# How to prevent lost focus in bootstrap modal?

Tags: firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3, focus, bootstrap-modal

Have a look on the boostrap site itself:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target

Though it has nothing to do with the topic in this paragraph, there you can open a modal with an input field and try the following: Focus an input field, type some chars, switch to another window or browser tab and then come back to the modal. In Firefox the focused input is not focused anymore.

How could I re-focus the last focused element? Or how could I even prevent the focus loss?

**Update**: filed an issue [on GitHub](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/18365).

Answer (score 4):

Along with @SHAZ solution, you also need `$(window).focus()` function to focus the input when browser tab is in active state

```js
$(function(){
   $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
      $('#myTextId').focus()
   });
});

$(window).focus(function () {
   var input = document.getElementById("myTextId").focus();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
      
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" id="myTextId" class="form-control" autofocus/>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uteewsjs/)

Comment: Okay, that should work somehow. It still requires that the LAST focused element gets re-focused (would need to be stored somewhere) and that if the modal is not open that $(window).focus() is turned off.

Answer (score 2):

Just **[focus()](https://api.jquery.com/focus/)** your input field when **[bootstrap's modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)** open everytime. For that use below code:

```js
$(function(){
   $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
      $('#myTextId').focus()
   });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
      
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" id="myTextId" class="form-control" autofocus/>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. AFAIK `shown.bs.modal` gets triggered only once: when the modal gets opened, but not when the window gets focus again after the focus has temporarily been elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on the accessibility fixes for such kind of issues (maintain keyboard focus with the modal pop).

Here is my code :

```
$("Your modal id").on('shown.bs.modal', function(event) {
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $('.close').focus();
    }, 1000);
});
```

The above code will FOCUS the pointer to the CLOSE (X) icon in the modal pop up.

To keep the focus (keyboard tab navigation) with the modal:

Once the tab focus comes to the close button :

```
 <a class="btn btn-default grey_btn" align="center" data-dismiss="modal" onkeydown="focusToClose(event);" href="#" target="_self"><span class="text">Close</span></a>

    function focusToClose(e)
    {
        if((e.key == 'Tab' || e.code == 'Tab') && !e.shiftKey)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
             $('#closeIcon').focus();
        }
    }
```

CLOSE (X) button code :

```
<button type="button" onKeyDown="blockFocus(event);" class="close" id="closeIcon" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

Happy coding.. :)

Comment: Please take a couple of minutes to format your answer. Hint: with 4 spaces at the beginning of a line the following text will be formatted as code. That is probably not what you want. Cheers.